# Zooming example in dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

In pure d3 I would use .call(zoom) on g element like this

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .on("zoom", myZoomFunction);
svg = d3.select('#my-chart')
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom);
```

Could you please provide me with an example on how I can do it using dimple.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid dimple doesn't have any native support for zooming.  It is an enhancement I would like to add in the future, but there is no work towards it yet.

Comment: Can we add zoom property through d3 functions in dimple?